# LARAVEL - eloquent get relation with null ids

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on some eloquent query. So the idea is that I have 2 models, let's call it **Files** and **Pricing**. Files **hasMany** so in pricings table I have `file_id` field. But I have default prices in pricings table which has `file_id = null`. I want to get files with pricing and also with these default prices which has `file_id = null`. The most important thing is that I would like to handle it with eloquent, because of some other relations that pricings table have. So I have an idea that in File model I am getting related pricing and default prices and then merge them. But I can't perform the query in an eloquent model to get default prices which have `file_id = null`. I want to get something like that:

```
public function filePricing() 
{
  return $this->hasMany(Pricing::class);
}

public function defaultPricing() 
{
  return Pricing::where('file_id', null);
}

public function pricing()
{
 return $this->defaultPricing()->merge($this->filePricing());
}
```

So in the controller, I would like to do:

```
File::with('pricing', 'pricing.[myNextRelation]')->get();
```

Or maybe anyone has a better idea to achieve it?

Comment: This `File::with('pricing', 'pricing.relation_for_pricing')->get();` is ok, according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: but the defaultPricing() model call does not work

Comment: Because it returns only relation itself. Not the relation data.

Comment: so is there any other way to do it?

Comment: It's possible to go with raw SQL. Please, provide all table names and wanted result, so I'll be able to help you